# AJAX - Post and Get Result from SERVLET

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I'm posting data to **Servlet** by using ***ajax.*** And I don't know how to **GET** result from Servlet. Please help me to solve this problem.
 I want to get Result from Servlet. If its success redirect to Success page, if its Failed, redirect to failed page.

**Ajax** getting response ***"success"*** but not redirecting to another page.
[this is response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6p5d.png)

This is what I have done till now:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {                       
    setInterval("ajaxd()",3000);

});

function ajaxd() { 

$.ajax({
  url:'/Query.cfm',
  data:{amount:'<%=amount%>', No:'<%=No%>', eno:'<%=No%>', fno:'<%=fno%>', sign:'<%=sign%>'},


  type:'get',
  cache:false,
  success:function(data){
     if (data == 'success') {
         var u = '/notic/succ.jsp?No=<%=No%>&amount=<%=amount%>';
         alert(u);
         window.location.href = u;
     }else if(data == 'failed'){
         window.location.href = '"/notic/failed.jsp?No="<%=No%>"&amount="<%=amount%>';
     }
   },
  }
 );
}

</script>
```

This is my **Servlet**'s response:
Result: can be "success" or "failed"

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getWriter().println(Result);
```

Comment: Can you provide your Servlet code as well? You probably need to write success / failed to the ServletResponse outputstream.

Comment: Ok. I would put a `console.log(data);` in your javascript inside the `success` function i order to see what `data` value is.  Also add an `error` and `done` functions below `success` to catch and log errors. Since you're not returning json you could also try adding `'dataType:text'` to your `ajax` call.

Comment: Try `window.location=u;` instead of `window.location.href=u;`

Comment: @C.Smith its not jumping to another page still...

Comment: does `alert(u);` show anything, if so what? if you look in your browser console do you see anything logged?

Comment: Also you could try this, since you're already using jQuery: `$(location).attr('href',u);`

Comment: `alert(u);` doesnt show anything... What do you think whats the problem? @C.Smith

Comment: if `alert(u);` never fires then its likely not making it into your success function. or are you saying the alert is empty, which seems hard to fathom since it is set immediately prior to the alert.

Comment: @C.Smith  `Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem was:**
due to using `println()` instead of

```
print().
```

Comment: It that doesn't fix it, perhaps you could add

Comment: console.log(data); after if (data == 'success') and post here what data is

Comment: I wish I could edit my comments... I meant to say:

If that doesn't fix it, perhaps you could add
console.log(data);
before
if (data == 'success') and post here what data is

Comment: Im getting success for console.log(data);

Comment: From the picture you posted it looks like your getting "success" with a new line after it (the "\n" isn't a visible character and shows up as an extra blank line).

    response.getWriter().println(Result);

to

    response.getWriter().print(Result);

I'll bet that'll fix it.

Comment: I agree this is worth a shot. Please try this and report on the results. Based on your previous comment, if the `alert(u)` is not firing then `data == 'success'` is not true

Comment: Yeah, worked, thanks a lot. I really appreciate it!